# Basis changing in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, change-of-basis

[image]

Hi can anyone help consolidate my partial answers to parts d) e) f), as I think I've gone wrong somewhere but do not know where.

d) firstly I found out what the matrix of $C$ looks like in base $B$:

$$\begin{align}[C]_B &= ([x^2-x]_B|[x]_B|[-x^2+x+1]_B)\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ -1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

So it is implied that $[C]_B [B]_C = $ Identity Matrix

So $[B]_C=[C]_B^{-1}$

Therefore $$[B]c= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Now for e)

I have first found $T$ in the basis $B$:

$$\begin{align}[T]_B &= ([T(1)]_B|[T(x)]_B|[T(x^2)]_B)\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0\\-2 & 2 & 1\\2 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Next I saw what $C$ looks like in the basis of $B$:

$$\begin{align}[C]_B &= ([x^2-x]_B|[x]_B|[-x^2+x+1]_B)\\
&= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\-1 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\end{align}$$

Now I computed the inverse of $C$ :
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1\\0 & 1 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

And have checked this is correct as $CC^{-1}$ is the identity matrix.

Then I proceeded to compute $[T]_C$:

$$P^{-1}[T]_BP = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

And here is where I get confused. As I suspected from being such a small part of the question, the generalisation of $[T]_C^N$ would have come from $[T]_C$ being idempotent and thus $N$ could be any integer but this is not the case or I've made a mistake somewhere.

So instead I've wrote:

$$[T]_C^N = \begin{bmatrix} 1^N & 0 & 0\\0 & 2^N & 0\\0 & 0 & -1^N\end{bmatrix}$$

Can anyone advise me one this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please use mathjax.

Comment: I don't know how to use it sorry

Comment: Can someone help me translate this into mathjax please. I can't get it to download on my computer as the site is soo confusing and I'm not familiar with the system.

Comment: There is nothing to download. Instructions for using mathjax are [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely revise this system.